Chrome password manager using wildcards in domain
Many of the websites in my organization use my Active Directory account/password for authentication so the password is the same on each site. However, chrome treats each site as unique, so when my AD password changes, I need to update the password on every single site. Is it possible to have a single username/password set for https://*.example.com and never have an entry for https://foo.example.com?
If necessary, I can migrate to Edge if it provides this functionality.

Most third-party password managers support this functionality.  I do not believe the Chromium password manager supports this functionality. Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome are both based of Chromium.

But if you set a password only for the website https://example.com, does it take for all the subdomains no ?
